# Nifi- converting json attributes as variables in executestreamcommand

Tags: json, replace, apache-nifi, update-attributes, routeattribute

i want to Convert Json Format attributes using python script.
   For example,if i have an Json format like this

```js
{"Sensor_name":"water","Sensor_id":"w1","Location_ip":"1.2","Sensor_value":"1002","Sensor_unit":"c89"}
 I want it like Sensor_name="water"
                Sensor_id="w1"  
                Location_ip="1.2"
                Sensor_unit="c89"
```

Comment: you want each value as flowfile attribut ?

Comment: Yes bro,actually I'm trying to get that day from http protocol as json data and convert it into attributes. Can you please suggest me any idea ?

Comment: you only want python script or other processor is accepted ?

Comment: I want python script and processor also. I will try the both

Comment: Use EvaluateJsonPath to extract values from json content to attributes. The executestreamcommand is not able to set attributes - it could only transform the content.

Comment: I will try it.thank you